# Javascript sinon.js spy working in one test case but not in other

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

This is my javascript class

```
var CommunicationInterface = inherit(Interface, {
  __constructor: function() {
    this.heartBeatDuration = 60 * 1000;
    this.client = null;
    this._isSetupped = false;
    this.__base();
  },

  setup: function() {
    // console.log('xmpp interface setup started');
    var _this = this;
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    if (this._isSetupped) {
      deferred.resolve();
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    CommConfig.get('params')
    .then(function(params) {
      _this.client = new Client({
        id: params.id + '@' + config('HOST'),
        password: params.password,
        host: config('HOST'),
        port: config('PORT'),
        reconnect: true
      });

      _this.client.on('online', _this.onOnline.bind(_this));

      setInterval(function() {
        _this.heartBeat.bind(_this)(params.id);
      }, _this.heartBeatDuration);

      _this._isSetupped = true;
      deferred.resolve();
    }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  },

  heartBeat: function(Id) {
    var stanza = this._makeMessage({
      'to': id + '@' + config('HOST'),
      'type': 'chat'
    }, '{}');
    console.log('foo');
    this.client.send(stanza);
    console.log('bar');
  },

  onOnline: function() {
    console.log('online');
    this.client.send('online');
    this.emitter.emit('online');
  },
});
```

and the test code is:

```
describe('CommunicationInterface', function() {
  var commInterface;
  var stubGetConfig, stubCommClient, stubCommClientConnect, spyCommClientSend;
  var clock;

  before(function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    stubGetConfig = sinon.stub(CommConfig, 'get')
                      .withArgs('params')
                      .returns(deferred.promise);
    deferred.resolve({
      'id': 'test',
      'password': '123456',
    });
    stubCommClientConnect = sinon.stub(CommunicationInterface.Client.prototype,
                                       'connect');
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  beforeEach(function () {
    commInterface = new CommunicationInterface();
    stubCommClient = sinon.spy(commInterface.client);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    stubCommClientConnect.reset();
    stubGetConfig.reset();
    stubCommClient.reset();
    clock.restore();
  });

  it('test 1', function(done) {
    commInterface.setup()
    .done(function () {
      var spyCommClientSend = sinon.spy(commInterface.client, 'send');

      commInterface.client.emit('online');

      assert.isTrue(spyCommClientSend.calledOnce);
      assert.isTrue(spyCommClientSend.calledWithExactly('online'));
      done();
    });
  });

  it('test 2', function(done) {
    var spyHeartBeat = sinon.spy(commInterface.__proto__, 'heartBeat');

    commInterface.setup().done(function() {
      var spyCommClientSend = sinon.spy(commInterface.client, 'send');
      clock.tick(commInterface.heartBeatDuration + 10);

      assert.isTrue(spyHeartBeat.calledOnce);
      assert.isTrue(spyCommClientSend.called);

      spyHeartBeat.restore();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The code in `test 1` is working fine and `spyCommClientSend` is created properly, but the second assertion in `test 2` fails and `spyCommClientSend` does not spy the actual object.

What could possibly be the reason here?

I am sure the `send` function is being called because the two `console.log` statements around it are printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I think the problem is in the fact that your spy is looking at `commInterface.__proto__.heartBeat`, which means that you are asserting that the `heartBeat` method on the `CommunicationInterface` *prototype* is called. This will not happen, because when you make sinon's clock tick, the `heartBeat` call is on the `commInterface` *instance* you created inside `beforeEach`.

This might be fixed by actually spying on `heartBeat` on the instance instead of the prototype, like so:

`var spyHeartBeat = sinon.spy(commInterface, 'heartBeat');`

Additionally, I would suggest that you cleanup `commInterface` inside your `afterEach` call by setting it to `undefined` or `null` -- just to ensure that you have a brand new, completely clean instance of `CommunicationInterface` with every test case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @grammar, thanks for the response. Another related problem is that `var spyHeartBeat = sinon.spy(commInterface, 'heartBeat')` does not create a spy on the function, which is weird. From the `console.log` output I can see that it is being called. So, either the spy is not being created properly, or its not able to detect it being called from `setInterval`. I am also cleaning up `commInterface` in `afterEach` but its not working as expected. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix this by moving the `clock` into `beforeEach` and using `sinon.sandbox`.

Comment: Ah yes the sandbox would have been my next suggestion. That way you have total control over the clock, the spies, and anything else. Glad you were able to get it working :)